# Why length is different in Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I'm learning Lua for corona sdk and I have these

```
local type1 = {nil, "(", nil, "x" ,nil , ")" ; n=6}
local type2 = {"(",nil, "x",nil, ")",nil ; n=6}
print(#type1)   --prints 6
print(#type2)   --prints 3
```

why the second one is not `6` too??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#` operator doesn't work on every table, it works only on a sequence, that is, the set of its positive numeric keys is equal to `{1..n}` for some integer `n`. In that case, `n` is its length. For instance, `local t = {"hello", 42, true}` is a sequence.

But both your tables are not sequence because they have "holes" of `nil`.

See [Lua 5.2 Reference Manual: The length operator](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.6).

Comment: I tried with table.getn() still print the same, so how can I count correctly an array?

Comment: @Kossel You mean you want to get the number of values including the ones that you initialized as `nil`? You can't, because a value of `nil` of some key is equivalent to has no value at that key.

Comment: To put it a different way: assigning `nil` to a value is essentially the same as deleting the entry at that value.

Comment: then why first is printing correctly 6 elements?? thats weird language :/

Comment: @Kossel It just happens to be correct for this particular table, but you can't rely on it.

Comment: @Kossel because it's undefined. Consider this series of of outputs: http://pastebin.com/Y8rqgq3k Lua simply doesn't try to error-check whether or not a sequence actually will have a sane "length" - it just returns what it returns, and it's up to you to only use it on things where it makes sense.

Comment: all right thats clear enough thanks, I replaced nil with false and worked as I expected

Comment: @Kossel # is defined as a position of (non-nil, nil) pair. In the *sequence* there is only one such place -- the end. In array with holes -- many, and any may be used. If you want to understand logic behind this: Lua table has two internal parts -- hash and array, both extended dynamically. So, if new index falls into (or near the end of) array, then it is inserted into array part, otherwise in hash. # returns last index used in array part. In your example, `type1` has 6 array slots and 1 hash (`n=6`), and `type2` has 3 array slots and 2 hash slots (for `[5]=")"` and `n=6`).

Comment: @user3125367 To be precise, in 5.2: if there is no hash part then the length of the array part is returned, otherwise a binary search is used: http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/ltable.c.html#unbound_search But you should never rely on this behavior anyway.